# using objects to get position (x, y) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, position

this code works:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("red"); 
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Left:" + myElement.offsetLeft + "px | Top:" + myElement.offsetTop + "px");
    }, 1000);
```

This prints out the position(x, y) every second

But If I try and change it to using objects:

```
function Enemy(id){
    this.id = getElementById(id);
    this.getCoordinates = function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log("Left:" + this.id.offsetLeft + "px | Top:" + this.id.offsetTop + "px");
        }, 1000);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var enemy = new Enemy("red");
    enemy.getCoordinates();

});
```

It prints out nothing - and I can't see where my mistake is.

Comment: `getElementById` is not a global function, use `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `setInterval` or `setTimeout` (or any event handler like onclick) the `this` variable refers to the global object. In a browser that's `window`.

In modern browsers you can do this:

```
setInterval((function() {
        console.log("Left:" + that.id.offsetLeft + "px");
    }).bind(this), 1000); // <------- bind
```

Otherwise all other solutions are basically similar to your first piece of code.

Note that there is an implementation of `bind()` in pure js from Mozilla that can be ported to older browsers. Search for it on MDN.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the value of "this" is changing within the setInterval.  The fix is to change it to:

```
function Enemy(id){
  this.id = document.getElementById(id);

  var self = this;
  this.getCoordinates = function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Left:" + self.id.offsetLeft + "px | Top:" + self.id.offsetTop + "px");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to qualify `document.getElementById()`, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Enemy(id){
    this.id = document.getElementById(id);
    this.getCoordinates = function(){
        var element = this.id;
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log("Left:" + element.offsetLeft + "px | Top:" + element.offsetTop + "px");
        }, 1000);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var enemy = new Enemy("red");
    enemy.getCoordinates();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As slebetman said, the 'this' variable is not what you expected. Try saving it in a 'that' variable, which can be accessed in different scopes.

```
function Enemy(id){
    var that = this; // reference to 'this' that can be used in other scopes
    that.id = document.getElementById(id);
    that.getCoordinates = function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log("Left:" + that.id.offsetLeft + "px | Top:" + that.id.offsetTop + "px");
        }, 1000);
    }
    return that;
}
```